# Fisher's exact test for bigger than 2 by 2 contingency table

Tags: python, statistics

Hi scipy stats has a implementation of Fisher's exact test but it is only for 2 by 2 contingency tables. I want to do the test on bigger than 2 by 2 tables. (5x2 ,5x3)
I know there is fisher.test in R which can do the job but I want to do it in my python code

Anybody knows an python implementation of Fisher's exact test that can work on bigger tables?

Also I am not sure if it is ok to do Fisher's exact test on bigger than 2 by 2 tables.

Thanks

Comment: How about a chi sqr test?

Comment: my values are not large, so i don't think chi sqr test would be appropriate.

Comment: Moreover and WAY MORE IMPORTANT: Chi square is an **approximation**, where Fisher is the **exact** test. We are getting more and more to the point where Chi square tests (or even the more reliable *G*-tests) are not even needed anymore. The exact tests just take enormous computer power - and that limitation slowly fade away :)

Answer (score 24):

Yes, it is ok to do a Fisher's exact test on tables bigger than 2x2.

There currently aren't any clean, widely tested solutions out there in python. One solution would be to use [rpy2](https://rpy2.readthedocs.io) and call the R function from python:

```
import numpy as np
import rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri.activate()

stats = importr('stats')
m = np.array([[4,4],[4,5],[10,6]])
res = stats.fisher_test(m)
print 'p-value: {}'.format(res[0][0])
>> p-value: 0.668165917041
```

Another solution would be to dig into the C code that the R implementation uses and to call that code directly. Here is a link to someone's [github project](https://github.com/maclandrol/FisherExact) where they went back to the original fortran implementation and call that from python.

Comment: Did not have an R installation, so went with the github project (https://github.com/maclandrol/FisherExact). I needed fortran compiler, and `brew install gcc` gave me the compiler I needed.

Answer (score 3):

By some simple calculation, we can extend the formula of hyper-geometric probability of 2 x 2 contingency table to any size of r x c. For example, the probability of a 2 x 3 contingency table can be found as

(N1!N2!M1!M2!M3!) / (N!a!b!c!d!e!f!)

where N1, N2 is the sum of each row, M1, M2, M3 is the sum of each column, N is the total sum, and a,b,c,d,e,f is the number in each cell.

You can implement Fisher's Exact Test by a depth-first search(dfs). The code:

```
import math

def _dfs(mat, pos, r_sum, c_sum, p_0, p):

    (xx, yy) = pos
    (r, c) = (len(r_sum), len(c_sum))

    mat_new = []

    for i in range(len(mat)):
        temp = []
        for j in range(len(mat[0])):
            temp.append(mat[i][j])
        mat_new.append(temp)

    if xx == -1 and yy == -1:
        for i in range(r-1):
            temp = r_sum[i]
            for j in range(c-1):
                temp -= mat_new[i][j]
            mat_new[i][c-1] = temp
        for j in range(c-1):
            temp = c_sum[j]
            for i in range(r-1):
                temp -= mat_new[i][j]
            mat_new[r-1][j] = temp
        temp = r_sum[r-1]
        for j in range(c-1):
            temp -= mat_new[r-1][j]
        if temp <0:
            return
        mat_new[r-1][c-1] = temp

        p_1 = 1
        for x in r_sum:
            p_1 *= math.factorial(x)
        for y in c_sum:
            p_1 *= math.factorial(y)

        n = 0
        for x in r_sum:
            n += x
        p_1 /= math.factorial(n)

        for i in range(len(mat_new)):
            for j in range(len(mat_new[0])):
                p_1 /= math.factorial(mat_new[i][j])
        if p_1 <= p_0 + 0.00000001:
            #print(mat_new)
            #print(p_1)
            p[0] += p_1
    else:
        max_1 = r_sum[xx]
        max_2 = c_sum[yy]
        for j in range(c):
            max_1 -= mat_new[xx][j]
        for i in range(r):
            max_2 -= mat_new[i][yy]
        for k in range(min(max_1,max_2)+1):
            mat_new[xx][yy] = k
            if xx == r-2 and yy == c-2:
                pos_new = (-1, -1)
            elif xx == r-2:
                pos_new = (0, yy+1)
            else:
                pos_new = (xx+1, yy)
            _dfs(mat_new, pos_new, r_sum, c_sum, p_0, p)


def fisher_exact(table):

    row_sum = []
    col_sum = []

    for i in range(len(table)):
        temp = 0
        for j in range(len(table[0])):
            temp += table[i][j]
        row_sum.append(temp)
    
    for j in range(len(table[0])):
        temp = 0
        for i in range(len(table)):
            temp += table[i][j]
        col_sum.append(temp)

    mat = [[0] * len(col_sum)] * len(row_sum)
    pos = (0, 0)

    p_0 = 1

    for x in row_sum:
        p_0 *= math.factorial(x)
    for y in col_sum:
        p_0 *= math.factorial(y)

    n = 0
    for x in row_sum:
        n += x
    p_0 /= math.factorial(n)

    for i in range(len(table)):
        for j in range(len(table[0])):
            p_0 /= math.factorial(table[i][j])

    p = [0]
    _dfs(mat, pos, row_sum, col_sum, p_0, p)

    return p[0]
```

You can test the code, for example:

```
print(fisher_exact([[1,24],[5,20],[14,11],[11,14]]))
```

give the result

```
0.0001228337404686859
```

which is the same as that given by R. There should be more elegant approach, while this code do give the right result.

Comment: useful-i checked it on a dummy dataset and it gave same result as the R library